# Virtuemart, force user registration/login before checkout

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm creating a site with VirtueMart 2.0 and Joomla 2.5.
Anyone can add a product to the cart, but I want to force the users to login/register before they go to the "Cart page/Chekout page".
Someone knows how can I do that?

Comment: Why would you force a user to login before seeing the cart page? The system already forces users to login/register before they can check out. There is no point in forcing them to do so before that point.

Answer (score 1):

In the Virtuemart Configuration Panel, on the "Checkout" tab, there are 2 checkboxes that you will want to set:

1. On checkout, ask for registration
2. Only registered users can checkout